# Generating a unique record for each xml sibling in csv output using XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I'm trying to transform the below xml into csv. Each record should be it's own entry in the csv output, however, I'd also like each "TO_Date" to generate a unique entry in the csv output for that ID. An example of the desired .csv output is underneath the XML. How do I best go about this? I originally thought a for-each would do the trick but I've not been able to get it to work, and I've read that using for-each for things like this is bad practice in XSLT.

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <Person_ID>0000002</Person_ID>
        </Person>
        <LOA_Event>
            <LOA_First_Day>01-02-2020</LOA_First_Day>
            <LOA_Last_Day>30-06-2020</LOA_Last_Day>
            <LOA_Reason Descriptor="Mat">
                <ID>2</ID>
            <LOA_Reason>
        </LOA_Event>
    </Record>
    
    <Record>
        <Person>
            <Person_ID>0000001</Person_ID>
        </Person>
        <TO_Event>
            <TO_First_Day>01-01-2020</TO_First_Day>
            <TO_Last_Day>03-01-2020</TO_Last_Day>
            <TO_Reason Descriptor="Other">
                <ID>2</ID>
            </TO_Reason>
            <TO_Date Descriptor="01-Jan-2020 - 1 Days">
                <ID>1</ID>
            </TO_Date>
            <TO_Date Descriptor="02-Jan-2020 - 1 Days">
                <ID>1</ID>
            </TO_Date>
            <TO_Date Descriptor="03-Jan-2020 - 1 Days">
                <ID>1</ID>
            </TO_Date>
            <Plus_or_Minus>1</Plus_or_Minus>
        </TO_Event>
    </Record>
</Data>



Person,FirstDay,LastDay,Reason,PlusMinus
"0000002","01-02-2020","30-06-2020","Mat",""
"0000001","01-Jan-2020","","Other","1"
"0000001","02-Jan-2020","","Other","1"
"0000001","03-Jan-2020","","Other","1"
```

Comment: I see an entry not only for  each `TO_Date` but also for `LOA_Event`. And I don't see where you got the values for the Reason and PlusMinus columns.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I'm wanting entries for each TO_Date and for LOA_Event. Is that possible? The "Reason" is from the descriptor of <TO_Reason> and the plus/minus is from the <Plus_or_Minus> in the xml.

Comment: Then shouldn't the reason be "Mat" in the first row?

Comment: Yes you're right. Apologies, it's because I manually typed the sample csv output.

Comment: *I'm trying to transform the below xml into csv* ... where is your XSLT code attempt? SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I originally thought a for-each would do the trick but I've not been able to get it to work

Actually, it's quite easy to do this with `xsl:for-each`:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data"> 
    <xsl:text>Person,FirstDay,LastDay,Reason,PlusMinus&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//LOA_Event | //TO_Date">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Record/Person/Person_ID"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(LOA_Last_Day | @Descriptor, 1, 11)"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="LOA_Last_Day"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="LOA_Reason/@Descriptor | ../TO_Reason/@Descriptor"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../Plus_or_Minus"/>
        <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this approach has two disadvantages:

1. The code handles two very different nodes in parallel, making it
   difficult to read and maintain;
2. Frequent walking up and down the tree to retrieve values from  ancestor/sibling nodes is inefficient.

OTOH, doing it with templates requires *much* more code:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Data"> 
    <xsl:text>Person,FirstDay,LastDay,Reason,PlusMinus&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="LOA_Event | TO_Event">
        <xsl:with-param name="personID" select="Person/Person_ID"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LOA_Event">
    <xsl:param name="personID"/> 
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$personID"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="LOA_First_Day"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="LOA_Last_Day"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="LOA_Reason/@Descriptor"/>
    <xsl:text>",""&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TO_Event">
    <xsl:param name="personID"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TO_Date">
        <xsl:with-param name="personID" select="$personID"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="reason" select="TO_Reason/@Descriptor"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="plusMinus" select="Plus_or_Minus"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TO_Date">
    <xsl:param name="personID"/> 
    <xsl:param name="reason"/> 
    <xsl:param name="plusMinus"/> 
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$personID"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(@Descriptor, 1, 11)"/>
    <xsl:text>","","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$reason"/>
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$plusMinus"/>
    <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```